# Still not understanding settingwithcopy warning

Tags: pandas

I want to isolate a string but I keep getting a setting with copy error. I read the other threads on settingwithcopy warnings but I don't understand why those solutions don't work here.

I've tried using:

```
df['Title'][i] = delBy[i]

df.Title[i] = delBy[i]

df[df.Title][i] = delBy[i]

df.loc[df.Title][i] = delBy[i]

df.loc[i]['Title'] = delBy[i]
```

Actual code:

```
delBy = df['Title'].str.extract(r'(.+?)(?= [bB]y)', expand = False)   
for i in df.index:

    if pd.notna(delBy[i]) == True:

        df['Title'][i] = delBy[i]

    else:

        continue
```

If title has keywords by or By (ex: Animal by John) keep only title (Animal). Leave other titles alone (ex: Meditations)

Comment: Did you try `df.loc[i, 'Title'] = delBy[i]`? However, I feel like there's a better way to approach your problem. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do and some example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you want to delete "by ..." part, where it can be done.

Then start from:

```
delBy = df.Title.str.extract(r'(.+?)(?= [bB]y)', expand = False).dropna()
```

(note that I added *.dropna()*).

Then, instead of your loop, just **update** this column (in place):

```
df.Title.update(delBy)
```

A shorter solution, isn't it?